# Upgrading of RAM

Tags: memory

I currently have [XMS3 Corsair](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/cmx8gx3m2a1600c9) 2x4gb RAM dual channel setup
and would like 12+ GB. I understand odd number of sticks and mixing of ram types is not optimal.

Is it best to just buy a new set of 2x4 XMS3 Corsair (to a total of 4x4)?
My [motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H77M_PRO/specifications/) allows 32 gb, I have four RAM slots.

Comment: Are you asking if you should purchase a 8 GB module or two 4 GB modules?  You already seem to known the answer to this question.

Comment: I want 12+ GB, that's it. I am asking if a new set of the same type 2x4 is the safe way. This is my first time upgrading RAM, im clueless.

Comment: Mixing of RAM **types** (e.g. both DDR2 and DDR3) wiill not work. I assume you mean same type but different values for CAS and similar. IN which case 1x4GB + 1x8GB will alsmost always outperform 2x4GB with dual channel. There are already several posts on that on this site though.

Comment: You know its not optimal.  So why not spend the extra cash to upgrade to 16 GB?

Comment: I didn't ask if 3 sticks is ok, Ram. By 12+ I mean I don't care what comes after. I take it you are saying that 4x4 is the best approach then.

Comment: There are only 2 ways to get 12 GB.  Three 4GB modules or one 8 GB and one 4 GB module.  If we seem confused you were very vague

Comment: "Is it best to just buy a new set of 2x4 XMS3 Corsair (to a total of 4x4)?"

Yes, yes it is.

Comment: To add to what @Hennes wrote in an above comment, you can't even *physically* fit for example DDR2 memory into a DDR3 socket because the two are physically incompatible. See for example [here](http://www.buildcomputers.net/ddr2-vs-ddr3.html) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Desktop_DDR_Memory_Comparison.svg) which both have nice comparisons of DDR2 and DDR3 modules. Note also that DDR2 needs a higher voltage than DDR3, so a DDR3 board will be unable to properly drive a DDR2 module (and the opposite is likely to cause damage, or at the very least not work at all).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I don't see anywhere where the OP mentions DDR2.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq No, but the discussion around "RAM type" came up in comments, specifically [Hennes'](http://superuser.com/questions/998686/upgrading-of-ram?noredirect=1#comment1379890_998686).

Comment: I respionded to ` I understand odd number of sticks and mixing of ram types is not optimal.`   I understand that the OP wanted to write something different and tried to push him/her to the right terminology.  (As well as trying to answer part of the OPs question ina commont followed by looking for similar answers on the site. At that time I considered a close as duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your goals.

Many current generation motherboard need to slow down when using more DIMMS (or vice versa, can use XMP setting to speed up when using one or one channel width of DIMMs).

So, fastest access to RAM would be 2x 8GB.

4x 4GB can be slower due to these slowdowns.

Yet -depending on use- 2x 4GB plus *$just about anything* is generally faster than just 8 GB. So if:

- Your funds are limited and you want the ability to add more momory at a later time without discarding anything you buy today, then get a single 4GB or 8GB DIMM and run with 2x4GB+4GB or 2x4GB+8GB.
- If your funds are sufficient and you want highest memory bandwith then get 2x8GB.

And ofcourse more memory tend to trump slightly faster memory access. So 2x8GB plus the old 2x4GB tends to win.

For completeness sake: Yes, you can also run 2x4GB and buy 2x2GB modules for a total of 12GB.

Comment: Whether your system has to slow down depends on the *processor* more than the motherboard because the memory controller is part of the *processor* not the motherboard. That said, the differences in real-world performance would be miniscule either way.

Comment: True. It depends a lot on the memory controller and the number of ranks it can address. And the memory controller is usually on the CPU die since AMD opteron / Intel core i7/5/3 CPU's.  For consumers board sit is often 2 slots with 2 rank max for max speed.  Server desktops differ,

Comment: x86 based servers are often affected by the same limitations.

Comment: True. But they also tend to ship with more memory slots (e.g. 6 rather than 4). And many server boards are multi socket. With one memory controller per installed CPU that also changes things.

Comment: Still the same principle though, whether it has 4 slots or 24.